# How to resize child div and images in it when parent div resizes

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div which contains a video `video-container`. 
I want to place icons on top of the video which are hyperlinks. So I made a `div` for the icons `link-container` and placed it inside the parent `div`.
Now if I resize the browser window video resizes but the child div remains the same size. I want the icons inside the child `div` to resize accordingly with the parent `div` so they always remain in the same position overlaid on the video (as if the icons were part of the video).

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="myvideo">
        <video />
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
        <a href="https://www.link.com/">
            <img class="imglink" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

.video-container {
  position: relative;
}

.link-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:10%;
}

.imglink {
  width: 100px; /*i also tried auto here*/
  height: 100px; /*i also tried auto here*/
  content: url('./assets/img.png');
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a relative unit on the width of your anchor tag and then you can make the image 100% width of your anchor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use percentage width: 100%

```css
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90vw
}

.link-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:10%;
}

.imglink {
  width: 10vw; /*i also tried auto here*/
  height: 10vw; /*i also tried auto here*/
  content: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGYAAABmCAMAAAAOARRQAAABHVBMVEX////qQzU0qFNChfT7vAWvx/k6gfSJrfc0f/TpOytMivT7twDqQTP7uQD/vQDqPzAmpUrpNiX++vrrVEnpMiD50c/8wgAdo0XqRzrwiYPpLBf/+/QqevPi8OW83cPs9e7oHwD63dvtamH1sKz75OP2uLX3w8DzpaH98vLynJfpOjf92pn8xk/936f+6sn91on7viL+9eb8z3j8ymH7wDRpmvbkuRqbzqZdtXJouXsAnzlRsWmBw5DvenLtY1nucmr7zozrTR/wdyj0kx/4qhHvaSzyhCXtWzD837kQcvPe5/3E1fvz5LulsDFzrUeeu/jDtS3w9P6Qrz9bqkzO5tM6i9kzqz09l7M4n4k3pmdAiuI+ksU6m5w6pXJkqrVHEHzgAAAE20lEQVRogb2Ya2OiRhSGETERRRkERYiiJl6TvaW7Fu/ZtrvtNtltml2bbrtt///P6AASuczADKDvR53x4ZzzzjmMDEOsWn840tbncjOXa8qbG20yqI/JdxOpP9A2XV3heVEUclCCIPK8pHeF9ahXy4jRm2wgQcwhJIiSLmv19KTxhaxISMQTitebWi8dRJOUSIZLUjb1xJD+ussL8RBboi4nA401nSdk7EDnCVJ3IUo0EAc0oTRDf6OQpssriS5zFzpB4TEBEUNqN3oyiCVlQ9gb+k2q0gfFN/sklHr0aYyXyBMUaJio9j5JcixloKem8HKsrQfdtBASyvAolPpRMtYnbpRpKDU5xsmCwEvKThIvIp6JgMKsI3ulICq8vB4N671+v1cfXmgy/CBAIqEMojqMIEnng8DpHg+1nG/okVDGURSFnyA7yHgg711DQmE2+MLw+gj/A0NBoqDgUyboWvT+iT01iCi1HM7LfC62EfZgSyeiMBMFV5VzgvExvtGJKGPcwdQ1gt3WYxLNsrc/XKIp5COXQGflxo8ojpIphbmqcI2fwhyFMGOkqnAc13iXC4D4TbaUj2XO4lTe+ziCmPH15RnnqPGzl6Mnf/lG6rrCuZx3e46UcWGY508YrlH+5fJAKXvKmQPaOVsaZUy55nxynC3wWV0pXb0oBziWs/lsDybUywoXUOP9ZTfrYPylcZ29zppy9iqM4bgPWWOuywhK+SxqS4FSD0zYAbaeRT5ZvkilX2/hnucITOVlJKaUp1LxjkEZDebsRaaYe7jnOxTmOkvMySnc8xpltOwxiGPDvYk0GjVmCve8oTYaLSZ/HMyRojkpHSdpFuZIFji8oW0LHP542pjDNxs7aYdvnXYXQA6C15ljEow12g5dYDBDuvwxCpM/wQqFaVnzBnVwqp/mUZhTvKYojDWkw1arcr+xi8ji4HWPisfGBD1Q/Z5lWWAmw6CimdrfBF5uq7+zlkAiykMrTLGNxviLU+U+sw4mUTiFIs4BvotH9dUX1lUnAQZl9eKt893+GmWXZSewoqfcIXJmjwFbu6xVq59YjxbbTIJxS8MwH8quj/2iTRuqMs7LoKNKIGG7tM3oKA8ICIxmv+Cq4vrYJ5WuPFPU0dznzPozpfo5TIEcGlefolKWb916llx9QVGgDcg59yiXQXnXdAAaQ543DKVV8K0yVRxnRuS3U0ws+cA6DAX6jY0/P7clZF12dw6vDFw4BIkz2T8wGGcGeDXDlQcGFOkEAwb8+CeSUyyEVnfw4cCAWLONZHRM1t73+DWPODUlxA5jEcFhgTozgqS2MQfuw4G//g4F1LpDYJgVPm1OSICdm8a2DbXdGuaMBd4EAPAt4DZvA/BqGY2xf0vdCYSf6fGfAAdTTOwhJZT6b8lTIF+b8WkbZQMCAY+zW2GXEdqAJCDX2UVMYTLiPH4tWok7mUZRMuAAFjr7BHVi/JyU9YEBfWvFUqAPUvoNcv4LtTKE2mw6kDqPviE/aZ4mcRQTFzvlYgVUg5gCG8IyGYhw2HoCSlAhwNKEsgtotaADgcUqyes9HQgs5ujJRwRSyWoE1FViiA0ylmpcSEBdmonS5VPbnKlYFJxzS8x7Ar06xmq5WPhGJoCTdKHOVkb6OPxqG+ZqNbMn+XI5X5nmljiK/wHna5fr0EEhEQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="myvideo">

      <video width="100%" >
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
        <a href="https://www.link.com/">
            <img class="imglink" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not resizing the image with the browser window,  unless i am doing something wrong.

Comment: i have updated, now it's purely screen base width

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resize based on the browser window dimensions, I would recommend using window-related units, such as: 
`vh` - viewport height
`vw` - viewport width

you can learn more about different measure units in CSS [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

My proposed solution for your particular problem is following:

```
<div class="video-container">
    <div class="myvideo">
        <video />
    </div>
    <div class="link-container">
        <a href="https://www.link.com/">
            <img class="imglink" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

.video-container {
  position: relative;
}

.link-container {
  position:absolute;
  top:70%;
  left:10%;

  /* for example 2% of viewport width / height */
  width: 2vw;
  height: 2vh;
}

.imglink {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: url('./assets/img.png');

  /* to avoid image stretching */
  object-position: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

In this example, if the viewport is 1000px wide and 500px high, the the container
will be 20px wide and 10px high. Assuming the icon is square, it will be of size 10px wide and 10px high aligned to the center of container.